# Serialize goroutines (parallelize but guarantee ordering)

Tags: go, parallel-processing

Let's say we want to process some computations in parallel but we have to guarantee that the ordering of the results is the same as the ordering of computations:

This can be done through for example:

https://play.golang.org/p/jQbo0EVLzvX

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    orderPutChans := make([]chan bool, 8)
    orderGetChans := make([]chan bool, 8)
    doneChans := make([]chan bool, 8)

    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        orderPutChans[i] = make(chan bool, 1)
        orderGetChans[i] = make(chan bool)
        doneChans[i] = make(chan bool)
    }

    srcCh := make(chan int)
    dstCh := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        go func(j int) {
            myGetCh := orderGetChans[j]
            nextGetCh := orderGetChans[(j+1) % 8]
            myPutCh := orderPutChans[j]
            nextPutCh := orderPutChans[(j+1) % 8]

            for {
                _ = <- myGetCh

                v, ok := <- srcCh

                if !ok {
                    k := (j + 1) % 8
                    if orderGetChans[k] != nil {
                            orderGetChans[k] <- true
                    }
                    orderGetChans[j] = nil

                    break
                }

                nextGetCh <- true

                time.Sleep(1000)

                v *= v

                _ = <- myPutCh

                dstCh <- v

                nextPutCh <- true
            }

            doneChans[j] <- true
        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
            _ = <- doneChans[i]
        }
        close(dstCh)
    }()

    orderGetChans[0] <- true
    orderPutChans[0] <- true

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            srcCh <- i
        }
        close(srcCh)
    }()

    for vv := range dstCh {
        fmt.Println(vv)
    }
}
```

One can use channels to pass around read/write permissions for the channels. The code is messy and doesn't look very tidy. Is there a cleaner way in Go to achieve that?

**Edit**:
I'm not asking for "simple" replacements such as using `chan struct{}` or using `close` on `doneChans` in favor of `doneChans[i] <- true`.

**Edit2**:

A much simpler approach (at least as far as code is concerned) would be to have a `results` array and the consumer sends the data together with an index (which is going to be mod number of workers) and goroutines write the result to `results[j]` and then have a WaitGroup to wait until all are done (with one batch of many batches) and then iterate through the results and send them to the destination channel. (Maybe not so good due to false sharing?)

Comment: If you want the results ordered the same as the inputs, give them an index of some kind and sort them when all results are ready. The order of concurrent operations is non-deterministic.

Comment: Waiting for **all** results to be ready is infeasible if you have gigabytes of data. One could of course split it into smaller chunks, process them, then sort those smaller chunks. Of course, you can also send things as "batches of computations" in my version as well. (I.e. send an array of ints, but of course, this is just demo).

Comment: > The order of concurrent operations is non-deterministic. 

That's certainly true of course. You might have computations that can be split into a part that you can run independently of each other but then have to process the results in a way where the order of the results is important and must be the same as the ordering of the input values.

Comment: Correct. Some synchronization is required to deliver a predefined order of results. Either you do everything sequentially in a single thread; you do everything multi-threaded then sort in a single thread, or you do everything in batches as you suggested, sorting the batches serially in a single thread, and using locking to ensure batches are delivered in order. Anything you try to do to achieve predictable ordering of concurrent operations requires synchronization, increasing complexity and reducing concurrency.

Comment: So you cannot, as the question title says, "Serialize goroutines (parallelize but guarantee ordering)". You cannot have your cake and eat it too: either it's synchronous *or* parallel; either it's guaranteed order *or* asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, but just because your second stage of your processing pipline requires things "in order" doesn't mean that you can't parallelize the first pre-processing step. My code serializes read and writes to/from the channels but the actual computation is still parallel. That's what I mean with "serialize".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174272/discussion-between-mroman-and-adrian).

Comment: If you need to maintain order channels is probs not the best thing to use then, however if you did want to use channels you can do something like this https://goplay.space/#VmVXYh2bHVk, additionally you can use channels and send the results to a redis zset where you can specify the zscore and let redis do the sorting for you.

Comment: One use case is when you have a file containing json data that you need to process using some "analysis function" that is order sensitive (meaning A,B won't produce the same result as B,A) and you can at least perform the unmarshalling in parallel to speed things up greatly. The unmarshalled entries are then feed through the "analysis function" in the same order as they were in the file.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this is the version of your code that uses a "pipeline" style. Where there are a number of steps in the pipeline:

1. Sending the src values
2. Workers that do work in the received src values, sending to their own results channel
3. Merging the slice of results channels from the workers into a single unordered channel
4. Ordering the unordered values from the unordered merged channel

Here is the code, it uses the Indexed pair style that you mention in the edits to your original question.

```
type idxPair struct {
    idx, val int
}

func main() {
    // add a done channel, an ability to stop the world by closing this.
    done := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(done)

    // create srcChan, this will be where the values go into the pipeline
    srcCh := make(chan idxPair)

    // create a slice of result channels, one for each of the go workers
    const numWorkers = 8
    resChans := make([]<-chan idxPair, numWorkers)

    // waitgroup to wait for all the workers to stop
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(numWorkers)

    // start the workers, passing them each the src channel,
    // collecting the result channels they return
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        resChans[i]  = worker(done, &wg, srcCh)
    }

    // start a single goroutine to send values into the pipeline
    // all values are sent with an index, to be pieces back into order at the end.
    go func() {
        defer close(srcCh)
        for i := 1; i < 100; i++ {
            srcCh <- idxPair{idx: i, val: i}
        }
    }()

    // merge all the results channels into a single results channel
    // this channel is unordered.
    mergedCh := merge(done, resChans...)

    // order the values coming from the mergedCh according the the idxPair.idx field.
    orderedResults := order(100, mergedCh)

    // iterate over each of the ordered results
    for _, v := range orderedResults {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}

func order(len int, res <-chan idxPair) []int {
    results := make([]int, len)

    // collect all the values to order them
    for r := range res {
        results[r.idx] = r.val
    }

    return results
}

func worker(done <- chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup, src <-chan idxPair) <-chan idxPair {
    res := make(chan idxPair)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer close(res)
        sendValue := func(pair idxPair) {
            v := pair.val
            v *= v
            ip := idxPair{idx: pair.idx, val: v}
            select {
            case res <- ip:
            case <-done:
            }
        }

        for v := range src{
             sendValue(v)
        }
    }()

    return res
}


// example and explanation here: https://blog.golang.org/pipelines
func merge(done <-chan struct{}, cs ...<-chan idxPair) <-chan idxPair {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan idxPair)

    output := func(c <-chan idxPair) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for n := range c {
            select {
            case out <- n:
            case <-done:
                return
            }
        }
    }
    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

The reason that I think this is slightly cleaner and not just "different for the sake of it", is because:

1. You can model and implement each of the stages independently. The `order` stage can be easily optimised to send values through a channel when they are received etc.
2. It's much more composable; instead of one large method that operates on a number of channels stored in arrays, you can do async work on elements and leave the ordering as something elses resposibility. This promotes reuse.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. This looks great. While looking at it I had another idea which basically revolves around one buffering results and once you have the result with the next index you send it to the result chan. (Essentially how you order UDP packets with packet numbers. You buffer packets that have a packet number > next packet and once you receive the packet that is supposed to be next you process it then scan forward in the buffer until the first "gap" and then rinse and repeat).

Comment: I think I'll construct some benchmark case and then try all the methods mentioned here in the comments/answers and publish the results. Would be interesting to see what gets the most throughput.

Comment: Great ideas, I had a similar kind of "buffering" idea in mind; omitted for simplicity. But may well work great. I hoped the idea above would be flexible enough to incorporate these optimisations easily!